# git fetch --unshallow gives :"fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense" error

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-clone, git-fetch

I am unable to git clone a remote repository using plain

```
git clone path
```

I get the error `"The remote end hung up unexpectedly"`.
The complete msg I get is :

```
Cloning into 'xyzabc'...
remote: Counting objects: 4328, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3861/3861), done.
select: Not enough memory2192/4328), 123.71 MiB | 164.00 KiB/s
ffatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
atal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I search online for a solution and after trying every other solution landed on solution of doing :

```
git clone --depth=1 path
```

followed by

```
git fetch --unshallow
```

Now the clone is completing fully. But, when I try to run git fetch --unshallow to recieve the complete project, I get the error :

```
fatal: --unshallow on a complete repository does not make sense
```

I dont know what to do please guide

Answer (score 12):

I too found the same message. Looks like it's not allowing to unshallow a shallow clone. You might want to try.

```
git fetch --depth=10000
```

assuming there are 10000 depths in your clone.

Answer (score 11):

`git fetch --depth=10000` remains necessary, but at least you now have a way to confirm your repo is unshallow or not with Git 2.14.x/2.15, Q4 2017.

See [commit 417abfd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/417abfde3534ad51a1a47e00ed799e40e3f7b4ae) (18 Sep 2017) by [Øystein Walle (``)](https://github.com/).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3430fff](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3430fff768b526a8e5877cfe56760d4865350b5e), 25 Sep 2017)</sup>

> ### rev-parse: `rev-parse`: add `--is-shallow-repository`
>
> "[git rev-parse](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse)" learned "`--is-shallow-repository`", that is to be
>   used in a way similar to existing "`--is-bare-repository`" and
>   friends.
>
> Running `git fetch --unshallow` on a repo that is not in fact shallow
>   produces a fatal error message.
>   Add a helper to `rev-parse` that scripters can use to determine whether a repo is shallow or not.

Comment: for usage see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531605/how-to-test-if-git-repository-is-shallow

Answer (score 9):

For Azure DevOps Build Pipelines, you need to go to the build pipelines => Edit => Triggers => YAML => Get sources

[image]

Save and re-run the build pipeline

Comment: Dude I have no idea why you decided to answer this very specific use case but it was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I would kiss you!

Comment: are you doing the az-400 exam? This is a timely post for sure. thx

Answer (score 0):

you are missing one step here,

after

```
git clone --depth=1 path
```

after this cd into your project directory,

```
cd <intoPartiallyClonedProject>
```

then,you need to perform
git fetch --depth=N, with increasing N
like

```
git fetch --depth=5
git fetch --depth=200
git fetch --depth=500
git fetch --depth=1000
```

and then perform

this is best explained in detail in this answer,

[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/62079208#62079208) by me i.e NikhilP

[error: RPC failed; curl transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618885/error-rpc-failed-curl-transfer-closed-with-outstanding-read-data-remaining/62079208#62079208)

upvote if it helps you.

Comment: This gives me the same error message in the same situation as `--unshallow`.

Answer (score 0):

Configurations that  helped with the error is
(In GitLab)

For each project :

1. On the top bar, select Main menu > Projects and find your project.
2. On the left sidebar, select Settings > CI/CD. Expand General
   pipelines.
3. Under Git strategy, choose git fetch, under Git shallow
   clone, enter a value, 1000, the maximum value for GIT_DEPTH Read More - [https://gitlab.yourcompany.com/help/ci/pipelines/settings#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone{}](https://gitlab.yourcompany.com/help/ci/pipelines/settings#limit-the-number-of-changes-fetched-during-clone%7B%7D)

In the .gitlab-ci-yml (this should be done before any command that calls GitVersion.exe)

```
  before_script:
    - git fetch --prune --tags --unshallow
```

Answer (score -4):

This message means you have already unshallowed your repository.