# How to Test if Git Repository is Shallow?

Tags: git

When I make a local clone from a repository, the clone fails if the origin repository is shallow.

```
git clone -l -- . target-dir
```

As that is not always the case I'd like to find out prior clone but don't know how to do that.

What I tried so far is very little, basically creating error messages on clone. At the moment I just fetch to unshallow and if that fails, I do a plain fetch because if the repo would be shallow, it should be unshallow afterwards:

```
if ! git fetch --unshallow; then
    git fetch
fi
```

However there is no guarantee for being unshallow afterwards (remote to fetch from can be shallow, too), so a test for the (un)shallowness of a git repository would be much better.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @Whymarrh: "How to Test if Git Repository is Shallow?", just edited, was using the title for the built-in search first.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If your Git is [2.15](https://github.com/git/git/blob/v2.15.0/Documentation/RelNotes/2.15.0.txt#L87-L89) or later, run:

```
git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
```

which will print `false` (not shallow) or `true` (shallow):

```
if $(git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository); then
    ... repository is shallow ...
fi
```

The answer below dates back to Git versions before 2.15.

---

If your Git is older than 2.15,<sup>1</sup> just test for the file `shallow` in the Git repository directory:<sup>2</sup>

```
if [ -f "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"/shallow ]; then
    echo this is a shallow repository;
else
    echo not a shallow repository;
fi
```

or (shorter):

```
[ -f "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"/shallow ] && echo true || echo false
```

You can turn this into a shell function:

```
test_shallow() {
    [ -f "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"/shallow ] && echo true || echo false
}
```

and even automate the Git version checking:

```
test_shallow() {
    set -- $(git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository)
    if [ x$1 == x--is-shallow-repository ]; then
        [ -f "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"/shallow ] && set true || set false
    fi
    echo $1
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup>`git --version` will print the current version number:

```
$ git --version
2.14.1

$ git --version
git version 2.7.4
```

etc.  (I have multiple versions on different VMs/machines at this point.)  You can also run:

```
git rev-parse --is-shallow-repository
```

If it just prints `--is-shallow-repository`, your Git is pre-2.15 and lacks the option.

<sup>2</sup>To see why there are double quotes around `$(git rev-parse --git-dir)`, see [Tom Hale's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37531605/how-to-test-if-git-repository-is-shallow/37533086?noredirect=1#comment125560270_37533086).  Note that testing this is a bit tricky since `git rev-parse --git-dir` from the top level of, e.g., the repository `/tmp/with space` just prints `.git`; you must be in a subdirectory, such as `/tmp/with space/sub` to observe the problem.

Comment: So as long as the repository is shallow there is the `shallow` file in the git-dir, isn't it? Giving this a test, sounds promising, thanks already for your answer so far.

Comment: From tests: Removing the shallow file makes git think it's not shallow and allows local clones. Next to that just noticing with my current git version that --local is ignored if it's detected shallow and cloned nevertheless falling back to non-local. Exit status code is 0 then.

Comment: The `shallow` file is not only the marker, it also contains the grafts that *make* it a shallow repository (vs just a broken one, if you remove the file).  It's not generally wise to just remove it: leave that to a `fetch` that successfully unshallows.

Comment: @torken: I removed it only for a test as I wanted to try out what happens. I do the check and if shallow, unshallow it via fetch.

Comment: To allow for spaces in directory names, be sure to double-quote properly: `"$(git rev-parse --git-dir)"`

Comment: @TomHale: good point, will update example snippets.

Comment: @TomHale Thanks for your comment, I'd like to extend and give the general suggestion to use pathnames only containing segments entirely from the portable filename character set¹ in the first place (git is distributed and therefore portability is a precondition for safe operation across the network.) Additionally it is required to check no segment starts with a dash, (git) symbolic names may have even more requirements. Cf. pathchk(1) -p option, ¹ https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/9340

Answer (score 1):

When you don't have access to the remote repository (not the case here, but still a possible scenario), a `git clone` is still a good way to test if that remote repository is shallow or not.

The problem is not transfer/create file needlessly when the clone would ultimately fail because of the shallow nature of said remote repository.

This is now fixed with Git 2.32 (Q2 2021): "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/22eee7f4554e777de93134c0ae06ee611bd570a4/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> new `--reject-shallow` option fails the clone as soon as we notice that we are cloning from a shallow repository.

See [commit 4fe788b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fe788b1b0ee6150173580d8fa70e7d5788cf7d3) (01 Apr 2021) by [Li Linchao (`Cactusinhand`)](https://github.com/Cactusinhand).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 22eee7f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22eee7f4554e777de93134c0ae06ee611bd570a4), 08 Apr 2021)</sup>

> ### [`builtin/clone.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4fe788b1b0ee6150173580d8fa70e7d5788cf7d3): add `--reject-shallow` option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Li Linchao</sup>

> In some scenarios, users may want more history than the repository offered for cloning, which happens to be a shallow repository, can give them.
> But because users don't know it is a shallow repository until they download it to local, we may want to refuse to clone this kind of repository, without creating any unnecessary files.
>
> The '`--depth=x`' option cannot be used as a solution; the source may be deep enough to give us '`x`' commits when cloned, but the user may later need to deepen the history to arbitrary depth.
>
> Teach '`--reject-shallow`' option to "[`git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe788b1b0ee6150173580d8fa70e7d5788cf7d3/Documentation/git-clone.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone))</sup> to abort as soon as we find out that we are cloning from a shallow repository.

No local file created!

The error message will be (with the test clone command):

```
git -c clone.rejectshallow=true clone --no-local shallow-repo
source repository is shallow, reject to clone.
```

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe788b1b0ee6150173580d8fa70e7d5788cf7d3/Documentation/config/clone.txt#L5-L8):

> ### `clone.rejectShallow`
>
> Reject to clone a repository if it is a shallow one, can be overridden by
> passing option `--reject-shallow` in command line.

`git clone` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4fe788b1b0ee6150173580d8fa70e7d5788cf7d3/Documentation/git-clone.txt#L152-L156):

> ### `--[no-]reject-shallow`
>
> Fail if the source repository is a shallow repository.
> The '`clone.rejectShallow`' configuration variable can be used to
> specify the default.